# Sorting an Array in TensorFlow

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, tensorflow

Let's assume I have an array in TensorFlow:

```
[ 0.12300211,  0.51767069,  0.13886075,  0.55363625],
[ 0.47279349,  0.50432992,  0.48080254,  0.51576483],
[ 0.84347934,  0.44505221,  0.88839239,  0.48857492],
[ 0.93650454,  0.43652734,  0.96464157,  0.47236174], ..
```

I would like to sort this array by the third column. How do I do this? I am able to sort each column individually using `tf.nn.top_k()`, which gives me the sorted values and the respective indices. I could use the indices of this third column to reorder the others, but I cannot find a reordering Op.

Assuming I want to keep things in-graph (no Python shenanigans):

- How do I sort (the above array) in TensorFlow?
- How do I re-order in TensorFlow when I have indices for re-ordering?

Comment: If I understand your question, this seems to be an [open issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/288). Nothing yet, but worse comes to worst, flatten and `top_k`.

Comment: That will not work if one wants to sort by the third column, or re-order with a list of indices.

Comment: You can probably re-order using [tf.gather](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/array_ops.html#gather)? Possibly?

Comment: Hey that's a nice find. I'm going to see if I can make a combination with `top_k` and `tf.gather`

Comment: Documentation for `tf.gather` seems to be [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gather) now.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The following works :

```
a = tf.constant(...) # the array
reordered = tf.gather(a, tf.nn.top_k(a[:, 2], k=4).indices)
```