# Sort 2D Tensorflow for all axis

Tags: python, sorting, tensorflow

I want to sort 2D tensor from minimum to maximum element pairs. I tried to do that by following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41857602/sorting-of-2d-array-min-to-max-in-tensorflow). It can sort it but not a perfect sorting.

This is my full code:

```
a = [[0.3,0.32],[0.1,5.2],[1.6,0.4],[0.3,0.1],[5.2,2.6],[0.5,1.15]]
a= tf.convert_to_tensor(a)

length = tf.size(a)/2
point = tf.gather(a, tf.nn.top_k(-a[:,0], k=length).indices)
```

and this is the output:

```
[[0.1  5.2 ]
 [0.3  0.32]
 [0.3  0.1 ]
 [0.5  1.15]
 [1.6  0.4 ]
 [5.2  2.6 ]]
```

The output are supposed to be sorted perfectly like this (look at `0.3` tensor):

```
[[0.1  5.2 ]
[0.3  0.1 ]
[0.3  0.32]
[0.5  1.15]
[1.6  0.4 ]
[5.2  2.6 ]]
```

Anyone can help? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort first according to the second column, then according to the first. This code (tested):

```py
import tensorflow as tf

a = [[0.3,0.32],[0.1,5.2],[1.6,0.4],[0.3,0.1],[5.2,2.6],[0.5,1.15]]
a = tf.convert_to_tensor(a)

def sort( a, col ):
    return tf.gather(a, tf.nn.top_k( -a[ :, col ], k=a.get_shape()[ 0 ].value ).indices )

point = sort( sort( a, 1 ), 0 )

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print( sess.run( point ) )
```

will output:

> [[0.1  5.2 ]
>    [0.3  0.1 ]
>    [0.3  0.32]
>    [0.5  1.15]
>    [1.6  0.4 ]
>    [5.2  2.6 ]]

as desired.