# How to sort a batch of 2D tensors in tensorflow?

Tags: sorting, multidimensional-array, tensorflow

I have a tensor `A` with the shape of `[#batch, #MaxSequence, #Features]`, where the actual lengths of the 2nd dimension (may be less than `#MaxSequence`) are stored in a tensor `L`. I want to sort `A` by the 2nd feature in the 3rd dimension on the sequence in each batch. I saw this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40784941/sorting-an-array-in-tensorflow) using `tf.gather` and `tf.nn.top_k` to sort a 2D tensor, but I don't know to apply it on the 3D case. Do I need to use loop to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have something working but it might exist better solutions. I guess my code is probably over-complicated for this simple problem.

The idea is that, we have to convert the return indices of `tf.nn.top_k(a[:,:,1].indices` (order by the second feature in the third dimension) to something [`tf.gather_nd`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gather_nd) can use. Particularly for my example below, we need to convert a tensor of

```
 [[3, 2, 1, 0],
  [0, 1, 2, 3],
  [2, 0, 3, 1]]
```

to

```
 [[[0 3], [0 2], [0 1], [0 0]]
  [[1 0], [1 1], [1 2], [1 3]]
  [[2 2], [2 0], [2 3], [2 1]]]
```

What I figured out:

- flatten the target indices first thus we get `[3 2 1 0 0 1 2 3 2 0 3 1]`.
- construct a paired vector intentionally `[0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 2 2 2]`
- `tf.stack` the above two vectors and then we reshape the result into what it is desired to be.

The complete tf code is below (`get_shape` method is defined [here](https://github.com/vahidk/EffectiveTensorflow#get-shape-)):

```py
import tensorflow as tf
a = tf.Variable([[[0.51, 0.52, 0.53, 0.94, 0.35],
                  [0.32, 0.72, 0.83, 0.74, 0.55],
                  [0.23, 0.73, 0.63, 0.64, 0.35],
                  [0.01, 0.74, 0.73, 0.04, 0.75]],
                 [[0.32, 0.76, 0.83, 0.74, 0.55],
                  [0.23, 0.72, 0.63, 0.64, 0.35],
                  [0.11, 0.02, 0.03, 0.14, 0.15],
                  [0.01, 0.00, 0.73, 0.04, 0.75]],
                 [[0.51, 0.52, 0.53, 0.94, 0.35],
                  [0.32, 0.00, 0.83, 0.74, 0.55],
                  [0.23, 0.92, 0.63, 0.64, 0.35],
                  [0.11, 0.02, 0.03, 0.14, 0.15]]], tf.float32)
batch_size, seq_length, num_features = get_shape(a)

idx = tf.reshape(range(batch_size), [-1, 1])
idx_flat = tf.reshape(tf.tile(idx, [1, seq_length]), [-1])
top_k_flat = tf.reshape(tf.nn.top_k(a[:,:,1], 
                                    k=seq_length).indices, [-1])
final_idx = tf.reshape(tf.stack([idx_flat, top_k_flat], 1),
                       [batch_size, seq_length, 2])
reordered = tf.gather_nd(a, final_idx)
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
print sess.run(reordered)

                 #ORDERED
                 #by this
                 #Column (within each example)
[[[ 0.01      ,  0.74000001,  0.73000002,  0.04      ,  0.75      ],
  [ 0.23      ,  0.73000002,  0.63      ,  0.63999999,  0.34999999],
  [ 0.31999999,  0.72000003,  0.82999998,  0.74000001,  0.55000001],
  [ 0.50999999,  0.51999998,  0.52999997,  0.94      ,  0.34999999]],
 [[ 0.31999999,  0.75999999,  0.82999998,  0.74000001,  0.55000001],
  [ 0.23      ,  0.72000003,  0.63      ,  0.63999999,  0.34999999],
  [ 0.11      ,  0.02      ,  0.03      ,  0.14      ,  0.15000001],
  [ 0.01      ,  0.        ,  0.73000002,  0.04      ,  0.75      ]],
 [[ 0.23      ,  0.92000002,  0.63      ,  0.63999999,  0.34999999],
  [ 0.50999999,  0.51999998,  0.52999997,  0.94      ,  0.34999999],
  [ 0.11      ,  0.02      ,  0.03      ,  0.14      ,  0.15000001],
  [ 0.31999999,  0.        ,  0.82999998,  0.74000001,  0.55000001]]
```

Note in the output, we have three examples. Within each example, the sequences are ordered by the second feature descendingly.

Comment: Thank you! This is not complicated at all (compared to loop). Can we apply it to sequences (the 2nd dimension) with variable lengths but are padded to `seq_length`? For example, the a[0][3][:] are filled with padding value 0.0, then the sequence actual length of a[0] is 3 and the actual lengths of a[1] and a[2] are still 4.

Comment: I think that `get_shape` will work that out as long as you pad with a vector of all zeros (all features are zero. thus after sorting these padded sequences become the last few sequences in an example.

Comment: Since I normalize each feature before reading them into this 3D tensor, some of them will be negative values. Maybe I should pad them with a very negative value (e.g. -9998.)?

Comment: Yes, that makes sense, at least for the 2nd feature (the one you sort on) you should make the change.

Comment: For this to run on my machine (python 3.5), I slightly changed `idx = tf.reshape(range(batch_size), [-1, 1])` to `idx = tf.reshape(list(range(batch_size)), [-1, 1])`.

Comment: Update: For this to work on the 1st dimension with the `None` size, I slightly changed `idx = tf.reshape(range(batch_size), [-1, 1])` to `idx = tf.reshape(tf.range(batch_size), [-1, 1])`.